# PHP File exists not working?

Tags: php, file, exists

I would like to check if a page exists. My file is article.php . The article's URLs are article.php?id=1 article.php?id=2 etc. But when I check it this way it doesn't work:

```
$filecheck = "article.php?id=$id";
if (file_exists($filecheck)) {
echo "This article exists.";
} else {
echo "Sorry this article does not exist.";
}
```

But it always returns "Sorry this article does not exist."
How could I fix this?

Comment: Why are adding query_string to your `$filecheck` var?

Comment: Unless you specify a full `protocol://host/path/file` type url, all file functions will assume you're doing a local file operation, and your code is looking for a file whose literal name is `article.php?id=XXX`, which is NOT likely to exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file "article.php?id=$id" will not exist as it is not a physical file.

I am assuming that you are using the $id to find an article that exists in a database. If this is the case then the file_exists function is not what you need.

What you will need to do is write a quick MySQL statement to check if the article exists and then go from there.

Something like this perhaps:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id='$id'";
$result = mysql_query($query);

// Check if result is there (ie article exists)
if ($result) {
    echo "This article exists.";
} else {
    echo "Sorry this article does not exist.";
}
```

I hope that helps. Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: No probs, glad it has worked for you. If you are happy with the answer please consider accepting it as an answer.

Comment: It seems he doesn't really care :)

Answer (score 4):

Don't pass the query string to it.

```
$filecheck = 'article.php';
```

Comment: If my reply solved your question please consider accepting it as the answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

It's because there is no file called: article.php?id=$id

There probably is a file called: article.php though :)

Answer (score 1):

If they are physical page instead of dynamically created content use this way:

```
$filecheck = "article_1.php"

if (file_exists($filecheck)) {
echo "This article exists.";
} else {
echo "Sorry this article does not exist.";
}
```

Otherwise check the ID whether it is in the DB.

Comment: Great suggestion! I will check if it is in the db. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Well the reason it is not finding the file is because you have a querystring in it. If you are by chance getting this data from some other source and can't control if a querystring is sent with it then you can do this:

```
$yourFile = 'article.php?id=$id'; // Or wherever you get this value from
$yourFile = strstr( $yourFile , '?' , TRUE );

echo $yourFile; // now has a value of article.php
```